# What's the difference between e.g. "room 5" and "number 5"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences

Is it correct to use the word "number" meaning "hotel room"?

Comment: In the right context it works.  In the wrong context there could be confusion.

Answer (score 4):

In an appropriate (though sometimes necessarily extremely contrived) context, most nouns can replace most other nouns. There are a number of natural contexts in which *number* can replace *hotel room* without causing any confusion, and some speakers will actually do this:

> As far as I know, the president will be staying in number 1. - No, he won't. Since number 1 is hard to secure,he has been assigned to three contiguous numbers on the fifth floor.
>
> Have you cleaned number 5 yet? - No, since the guest was still present. But two guests on the second floor left early, so I got their numbers done earlier.
>
> Is this your room key? - No, it's actually for a different number.

But in most contexts this doesn't work at all:

> Hello, we would like a number for two until Sunday.
>
> I have booked a number at the Hilton for you, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You book a room, you don't book a number.
It's therefore more common to ask “Can I have the key to room 30, please?” especially in a large hotel than “Can I have the key to number 30, please?” The first is idiomatic, the second is only grammatical.

Examples:

> [Room 101](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_39) *is **a room** introduced in the climax of the novel Nineteen Eighty-Four by George Orwell.*
>
> [Room 148](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1408_%28film%29#Plot) Through an anonymous warning, Mike eventually learns of the Dolphin **Hotel** in New York City, which houses the infamous "**Room 1408**." Interested, yet skeptical, Mike decides to spend one night in the hotel although manager Olin (Jackson) warns him strongly against it. Mike has a series of bizarre experiences in the room.
>
> [Room 222](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_222) *The TV series focused on an American history **class** at the fictional Walt Whitman High School in Los Angeles, California ...*
>
> [Room 237](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_%28film%29#Plot) *Danny asks if there is anything to be afraid of in the **hotel**, particularly **room 237**. Hallorann tells Danny that the hotel has a "shine" to it along with many memories, not all of which are good. He also tells Danny to stay out of **room 237**.*

Comment: Number 30 would typically be a street address rather than a room, at least in UK English.

Answer (score -1):

Talking like this :

> Which room do you have?
>
> The number 4.

will be understood.

But if you are trying to contact the owner of the hotel to describe a problem in the room number 5, I think you should not save your words.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, nor does it represent natural English speech patterns.